Spring Batch How to reject records when the resources are not available
There are several ways to rejects records in Spring Batch and all are related to Skip Listener. What would be the best way to reject records(In case of record object dependent resources are not available).
Example :- Processing a file record that requires PDF should be available and is not yet available and will be available later by an external job that pushes the pdf. Basically we want an automated way to reprocess the records after PDF is available.
What would be the best way.

Verify PDF available in the reader .
Verify PDF available in the Processor and return object as Null if not available and file will be reprocessed again.
Any other alternatives

What we tried in reader to set attribute and return object as null in processor
Reader:-
 fileScannerDTO.setPdfFileNotExist(!Files.exists(Paths.get(fileScannerDTO.getFilePath())));

Processor:-
 if(fileScannerDTO.isPdfFileNotExist())
    {return null;}


IMO, this logic of checking the availability of the PDF should not be part of the job itself. Try to setup a file watcher that detects the presence of new files and launches the job when needed.
Making the reader wait for the file to come is not optimal and works against the idea of batch processing where the input is expected to be ready when the job starts.
